# Programmatically logging into DotNetPanel using PHP

Tags: php, authentication, post, viewstate

I use software called DotNetPanel (DNP) and I'm modifying PHProxy to automatically log into the administration panels for me.  I've done this for several other types of software - like cPanel - just fine using authentication headers or POST variables, but DNP uses something I'm not familiar with - ViewState.

1. When I POST the user/pass data the page refreshes like nothing even happened.
2. When I POST the user/pass/__VIEWSTATE data the page produces a http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;323744 error.

Any ideas?

What is funny is if I write a javascript function to fill in the same information and the page and simulate a 'click' on the login button it works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and find out exactly what's happening when you log-in normally (ie: what's being posted, cookies that are being set, authentication methods, etc.) and reproduce that with PHProxy or whatever. To see that information, try using a tool like [LiveHTTPHeaders](http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/).

Comment: I actually am using LiveHTTPHeaders and am reproducing the POST variables and path exactly as they're sent.  I've also used wireshark just for kicks.

Comment: @gnucom Since you are using wireshark, can you tell if there's a difference between what your browser sends and what your script sends?

Comment: Have you tried understanding how ViewState works? Here's some documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx

Comment: Okay, so it turns out I wasn't passing all of the headers exactly the same.  Things like Keep-Alive and Accept-Encoding were required in order to get the IIS server to response correctly.  Once I created the identical headers, the IIS server responded perfectly.  Ergo, this had nothing to do with viewstate.  Thanks for your suggestions.